# Creating a sum of a range without loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, benchmarking

is it possible to create a sum of ranges in javascript without using loops? This is to increase the speed of the code. For example:

### JavaScript Range Sum:

```
#!/usr/bin/env js60

var j = 0, k = 100000000 + 1
for(i = 0 ; i < k ; ++i) { j += i }
console.log(j)
```

### Ruby Range Sum:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts (1..100_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000).sum
```

### Benchmarks:

1. Java Script Range of Sum:

```
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time js60 p.js 
5000000050000000

real    0m0.531s
user    0m0.519s
sys 0m0.011s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time js60 p.js 
5000000050000000

real    0m0.514s
user    0m0.502s
sys 0m0.012s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time js60 p.js 
5000000050000000

real    0m0.558s
user    0m0.531s
sys 0m0.027s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚
```

2. Ruby:

```
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time ruby q.rb 
5000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000

real    0m0.105s
user    0m0.088s
sys 0m0.017s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time ruby q.rb 
5000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000

real    0m0.122s
user    0m0.121s
sys 0m0.000s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚ time ruby q.rb 
5000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000

real    0m0.118s
user    0m0.094s
sys 0m0.023s
┌┄┄[sourav::archlinux]┈[/tmp]
└──╼⮚
```

How can I work fast like Ruby in JS?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an algorithm to calculate the sum of the range, if you want.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + (x - 1) + x
```

is equivalent to

```
x * (x + 1) / 2
```

```js
// Look at the result in the browser console, not the snippet console
const sum = (n) => (n * (n + 1n)) / 2n;
console.log(
  sum(
    100_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000n
  )
);
```

I bet this is the same sort of thing that Ruby does - it doesn't count up every number individually, it uses a summing algorithm.

Note the use of a BigInt because `100_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000` is too large to be represented precisely in Javascript as a `number`.

Comment: Umm... So that's what Ruby is doing under the hood when a block isn't passed... Clever...

Comment: For Rubyists, I believe in Ruby the sum method is implemented like this:
`Range.define_method(:sum2) { max ? max * max.next.to_i / 2 - first.-(1) * first / 2 : 0 }`. Consider a range `(4..10)`, the max gets the last element from the range, calculate `x * x + 1 / 2` which returns the sum of `(1..10)` then subtracts the extra sum of `(1..3)`. It should work with all the ranges like `(3..2).sum2 #=> 0`, `(5..5).sum2 #=> 5` and for ranges like `(5...5).sum2 #=> 0`. The same can be translated to JS pretty easily.